# How to run php scripts from c++ via fastcgi

Tags: php, c++, content-management-system, fastcgi

I am writing a C++ webserver for a high(er) performance CMS. We first used PHP for everything but we noticed performance issues. However I can not ask the front-end developers to write the views / templates in C++ code. So I want to run a FastCGI server (I dont know the right name) which holds a PHP FastCGI app. So when the application needs to render a View, the views passes data to a PHP script via FastCGI, PHP renders the HTML (or something like that), sends it back to the View, via FastCGI, and the C++ application sends the HTML back to the client.

Does somebody knows a better solution or where i can find a good FastCGI server or keywords so i can find it my self (on Google).

Comment: Please don't write tags in question titles.

Comment: Sorry, i am used to it (on forums). Dont going to happen again.

Comment: Err isn't this what Apache does?

Comment: Yes, sort of. But write my own C++ server because i cant use the normal vhost system of apache etc. So i write the whole http server in C++ and have to include php in a way. (so sort of the other way around :P)

Comment: Cool at least you have a reason! Have a look at the ngnix source code. It should give you a few pointers on how to implement FastCgi.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
http://php-fpm.org/

> PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is
>   an alternative PHP FastCGI
>   implementation with some additional
>   features useful for sites of any size,
>   especially busier sites.